# analyzer require 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, analyzer, build-runner

I did a mistake by migrating to null-safety then every thing become error, after fixing a lot of errors, I still get an error and the error is :

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 452ms

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph...
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 131ms

[INFO] Checking for updates since last build...
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 791ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Running build completed, took 30ms

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 79ms

[SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/injection.config.dart (cached):

This builder requires Dart inputs without syntax errors.
However, package:invoice_app/injection.config.dart (or an existing part) contains the following errors.
injection.config.dart:18:48: This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
injection.config.dart:18:12: This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.

Try fixing the errors and re-running the build.

[SEVERE] Failed after 123ms
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you can use this command to get out null safety mode `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

Comment: that is my problem, i have done that before now it tells me to do opposite

Comment: Did you find any solution except removing question mark ?

Answer (score 1):

it's look like injectable generator have some mix up with the new version of dart that is why when I generate new `injection.config.dart` file then it gave this error

> injection.config.dart:18:12: This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.

so if you want to fix it just open the file then then remove the `?` mark like from this

```
_i1.GetIt $initGetIt(_i1.GetIt get,
    {String? environment, _i2.EnvironmentFilter? environmentFilter}) {
  final gh = _i2.GetItHelper(get, environment, environmentFilter);
  return get;
}
```

to this

```
_i1.GetIt $initGetIt(_i1.GetIt get,
    {String environment, _i2.EnvironmentFilter environmentFilter}) {
  final gh = _i2.GetItHelper(get, environment, environmentFilter);
  return get;
}
```

I know it's not a solution but it works until when I will migrate to non-nullable, I will use this.